# Read credit card with JavaScript NDEFReader

Tags: javascript, nfc

I have an Android phone that is NFC enabled. I have a small Web app that is running on my localhost (HTTPS) that serves up a Web page containing the example code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NDEFReader/scan. When I load the page into my Android phone and try to read my credit card I get a "readingerror." Is there a setting or some other paramter that I need to set in order to read the card?

The code I am using is below. I do get the message "Scan started successfully." I also feel the phone vibrate when it reads the card, before I get the error "Error! Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try a different one?" And yes, I've tried with a different card and with a different phone and got the same result.

Can anyone help me out?

```
const ndef = new NDEFReader();
ndef
  .scan()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Scan started successfully.");
    ndef.onreadingerror = (event) => {
      console.log(
        "Error! Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try a different one?",
      );
    };
    ndef.onreading = (event) => {
      console.log("NDEF message read.");
    };
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(`Error! Scan failed to start: ${error}.`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A credit card does not store it's data in the NDef format.

You cannot read a credit card via the javascript WebNFC methods.